# How to create multiple dataframes using multiple functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I quite often write a function to return different dataframes based on the parameters I enter. Here's an example dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Category':np.random.choice( ['Group A','Group B','Group C','Group D'], 10000),
'Sub-Category':np.random.choice( ['X','Y','Z'], 10000),
'Sub-Category-2':np.random.choice( ['G','F','I'], 10000),
'Product':np.random.choice( ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'], 10000),
'Units_Sold':np.random.randint(1,100, size=(10000)),
'Dollars_Sold':np.random.randint(100,1000, size=10000),
'Customer':np.random.choice(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10,25,dtype='str'),10000),
'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/31/2018',  
                      freq='M'), 10000)})
```

I then created a function to perform sub-totals for me like this:

```
def some_fun(DF1, agg_column, myList=[], *args):
    y = pd.concat([
    DF1.assign(**{x:'[Total]' for x in myList[i:]})\
            .groupby(myList).agg(sumz = (agg_column,'sum')) for i in range(1,len(myList)+1)]).sort_index().unstack(0)
    return y
```

I then write out lists that I'll pass as arguments to the function:

```
list_one = [pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A'),'Category','Product']
list_two = [pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A'),'Category','Sub-Category','Sub-Category-2']
list_three = [pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A'),'Sub-Category','Product']
```

I then have to run each list through my function creating new dataframes:

```
df1 = some_fun(df,'Units_Sold',list_one)
df2 = some_fun(df,'Dollars_Sold',list_two)
df3 = some_fun(df,'Units_Sold',list_three)
```

I then use a function to write each of these dataframes to an Excel worksheet. This is just an example - I perform this same exercise 10+ times.

My question - is there a better way to perform this task than to write out df1, df2, df3 with the function information applied? Should I be looking at using a dictionary or some other data type to do this my pythonically with a function?

Comment: are all the lists for the individual data frames unique?

Comment: Hi! There could be duplicate lists passed to the function, but I’d use a different agg_column in the function call. If it’s easier, I’d also be fine to change the function to put the agg_column inside the list. Thanks!

Comment: @keg5038 Does your example code work on your end? When I try to go through thse steps, `df1 = some_fun(df,'Units_Sold',list_one)` only returns an error `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'` after the step `DF1.assign(**{x:'[Total]' for x in myList[i:]}).groupby(myList).agg(sumz = (agg_column,'sum')) for i in range(1,len(myList)+1)]).sort_index().unstack(0)`

Comment: @vestland I should have been more explicit - this code is using Pandas 0.25 which allows a Groupby aggregation with relabeling (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling). For older versions of Pandas, you could alter the function to have .agg({agg_column:'sum'}) instead of .agg(sumz = (agg_column,'sum'))

Comment: It's quite hard to say but my guess is to use a nested dictionary for both the `agg_column` and the `pd.Grouper` calls. this should get you very close. other than that maybe a few classes or well defined functions? it depends on how many variances of the `lists` there are as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

as Thomas has suggested we can use a dictionary to parse through your data, but with some minor modifications to your function, we can use the dictionary to hold *all* the required data then pass that through to your function.

the idea is to pass two types of keys, the list of columns and the arguments to your `pd.Grouper` call.

```
data_dict = {
    "Units_Sold": {"key": "Date", "freq": "A"},
    "Dollars_Sold": {"key": "Date", "freq": "A"},
    "col_list_1": ["Category", "Product"],
    "col_list_2": ["Category", "Sub-Category", "Sub-Category-2"],
    "col_list_3": ["Sub-Category", "Product"],
}
```

---

```
def some_fun(dataframe, agg_col, dictionary,column_list, *args):

    key = dictionary[agg_col]["key"]

    frequency = dictionary[agg_col]["freq"]

    myList = [pd.Grouper(key=key, freq=frequency), *dictionary[column_list]]

    y = (
        pd.concat(
            [
                dataframe.assign(**{x: "[Total]" for x in myList[i:]})
                .groupby(myList)
                .agg(sumz=(agg_col, "sum"))
                for i in range(1, len(myList) + 1)
            ]
        )
        .sort_index()
        .unstack(0)
    )
    return y
```

---

#### Test.

```
df1 = some_fun(df,'Units_Sold',data_dict,'col_list_3')
print(df1)
                                 sumz                      
Date                   2016-12-31 2017-12-31 2018-12-31
Sub-Category Product                                   
X            Product 1      18308      17839      18776
             Product 2      18067      19309      18077
             Product 3      17943      19121      17675
             [Total]        54318      56269      54528
Y            Product 1      20699      18593      18103
             Product 2      18642      19712      17122
             Product 3      17701      19263      20123
             [Total]        57042      57568      55348
Z            Product 1      19077      17401      19138
             Product 2      17207      21434      18817
             Product 3      18405      17300      17462
             [Total]        54689      56135      55417
[Total]      [Total]       166049     169972     165293
```

as you want to automate the writing of the 10x worksheets, we can again do that with a dictionary call over your function:

```
matches = {'Units_Sold': ['col_list_1','col_list_3'],
          'Dollars_Sold' : ['col_list_2']}
```

then a simple for loop to write all the files to a single excel sheet, change this to match your required behavior.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('finished_excel_file.xlsx')
for key,value in matches.items():
    for items in value:        
        dataframe = some_fun(df,k,data_dict,items)
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,f'{key}_{items}')
writer.save()
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is brilliant & I'm sorry for the delay in responding - I needed the opportunity to test it out as it was over my head initially. So far it has worked great & I will continue to test it. I am piecing together the logic on it but sincerely appreciate your thoughtful response! Thanks!

Comment: no problem, if there is a specific part where you need help I'll be happy to oblige @keg5038

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary would be my first choice:

```
variations = ([('Units Sold', list_one), ('Dollars_Sold',list_two), 
              ..., ('Title', some_list)])

df_variations = {}

for i, v in enumerate(variations):
     name = v[0]
     data = v[1]
     df_variations[i] = some_fun(df, name, data)
```

You might further consider setting the keys to unique / helpful titles for the variations, that goes beyond something like 'Units Sold', which isn't unique in your case.